# Square cut corners with CSS - is this ok?

Tags: html, css

I've been given a task to create some responsive square corners that appear to be cut on the edges.

I've come up with something that works.

So, the code below works, and it's the expected result. However, I'm not the king of CSS so am I wondering if anyone more experience they I can say, something like:

*"Oh that?! I can accomplish it using one single line of code. :p"*

Or

*"Oh?! That?! That's so dummy. Look at this alternative!".*

Is that the case?

Thank you in advance.

For your consideration, the code:

```css
p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.module-wrapper {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

.sub-module {
  margin: 0 -5px;
}

.sub-module p {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.type {
    background-color: red;
}

.local {
  background: black;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


.local p {
    background-color: black;
}

.title {
  background: green;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.title p {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-wrapper">
<div class="title">
  <div class="sub-module">  
      <p class="title">
          Jump Session Outdoor Editon
      </p>
  </div>
</div>    
<div class="sub-module type">
    <p>Party</p>
</div>
<div class="local">
  <div class="sub-module">  
      <p>
          London
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks again

Comment: I think that's a very elegant solution

Comment: Have you tried asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? They provide reviews of working code, whereas SO is more about fixing broken code, to my knowledge. (EDIT: the square corners do look good btw!)

Comment: You can use CSS pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` to reduce the number of elements.

Comment: [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/hcbkx1a8/)

Comment: @Vucko thanks for sharing. indeed, you do have a much simpler html structure, by the other hand, the css is a little more complex. Just a note that the white corners should be transparent, because the background of this page has some effects on it, and white wouldn't work. Anyway, thanks for sharing it, really.

Answer (score 3):

If I were trying to accomplish the same task I would probably pursue the :before and :after pseudo class. This will significantly clean up the HTML markup. An example can be seen here, I only did the top to illustrate the style.

http://codepen.io/justindunham/pen/ayFAo

```
<ul>
  <li class="bg-red sq-cut-top">Title One</li>
  <li class="bg-green">Title Two</li>
  <li class="bg-black">Title Three</li>
</ul>

.sq-cut-top:before {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Edit: Added HTML per comment, still too much CSS to post

Comment: Great job shrinking the OP's code and making it semantic, but the above code snippet is missing the HTML that goes with it. It's better if we don't have to click on the link to understand what you mean

Comment: Hmm... It seems interesting. But it doesn't display the bottom corners, and it doesn't work with `transparent` set on `background-color`. I presume if I do that, with that setup, I will have the elements background appearing instead. If you can edit that, I will gladly mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: This method would not work with a transparent background, you are correct, it would have to match a solid background. I updated the pen with a .sq-cut-bottom class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could always name the class using the [BEM methodology](http://bem.info).
This will cut down a few lines of HTML and CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="cutCorners">
    <div class="cutCorners-top">
        <p class="cutCorners-sub">Jump Session Outdoor Editon</p> 
    </div>

    <p class="cutCorners-sub">Party</p>

    <div class="cutCorners-bottom">
        <p class="cutCorners-sub">London</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.cutCorners { 
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.cutCorners-sub { 
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 -5px;

    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;

    background: red;
}

.cutCorners-top { 
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.cutCorners-bottom { 
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.cutCorners-top,
.cutCorners-top .cutCorners-sub {
    background: black;
}

.cutCorners-bottom,
.cutCorners-bottom .cutCorners-sub {
    background: green;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyw89xo6/).